# Undefined Control Sequence while using \itemize in beamer. If I change it from beamer to article, it works

Tags: undefined

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
.\\
\vspace{3.5cm}
\centering{\Huge\textbf{DELIMITERS}}

\newpage
.\vspace{1cm}
\\ A \textbf{Delimiter} act as a symbol that acts
logically like parenthesis, with a pair of delimiters enclosing an expression.

They can only be used in Math mode.\\The delimiters recognized by \textit{LaTeX} includes:
\newpage
.\\
\vspace{1cm}
Delimiters in Formula should be big enough to fit around the formula they delimit (for example around arrays).To obtain "Stretchable" delimiters type \verb+\left +or \verb+\right+ command

For Example by writing :\hspace{10pt}
\verb+\left( + $x^2$ \verb+ \right) + \\we will get output as: \hspace{10pt}
$\left(x^2 \right)$
\newpage
.\\
\vspace{1cm}
The two \verb+\left+ and \verb+\right+ commands must come in matching pair but the matching delimiters need not to be the same.\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
$x+y+z=\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\ b\end{array}\right[$\\
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\verb^ $x+y+z=\left(\begin{array}^\hspace{3pt}
\verb^{c}a\\ b\end{array}\right[$^
\end{minipage}\vspace{0.5cm}
Some formula require delimiter on one side only.So we can hide a delimiter by adding "." after the \verb+\left+ or \verb+\right+ command.\\
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
$x=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
y  &  \mbox{if $y>0$}\\
x+y   & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right[$
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\verb%$x=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}%
\verb%\mbox{if$y>0$}\\%
\verb%& \mbox{otherwise}\end{array}%
\verb% \right[% 
\end{minipage}

\newpage
.\\
\vspace{1cm}
{\huge \textbf{EXAMPLE}}
\begin{flushleft}
\verb+$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}x_1 & x_2 &+\\ \verb+x_3\\y_1 & y_2 & y_3\\ z_1 & z_2 &+\\ \verb+z_3\end{array}\right]$+\\ \vspace{1cm}
  \textbf{  Will show output as:-}
  $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   x_1     & x_2  &  x_3 \\
    y_1    & y_2  &   y_3  \\
    z_1    &  z_2 &   z_3
   \end{array}
   \right]$$
   \end{flushleft}


\newpage
.\\
\vspace{3.5cm}
\centering\textbf{\Huge ELLIPSES}
\newpage
.\\
\vspace{1cm}
\textbf{Ellipses} are small dots used in typesetting Mathematical Equations to denote continuation of something. 
\begin{itemize}
 \item abab\\
 \item jdhd
\end{itemize}
nsns
\newpage
.\\
\vspace{.8cm}
{\huge \textbf{EXAMPLE}}
\begin{flushleft}
\verb+$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}+
\verb+\mathbf{x{_11}}&  \mathbf{x_{12}}& + \verb+\mathbf{\cdots}&+
\verb+\mathbf{x_{1n}}& \\+
\verb+\mathbf{x_{21}}& \mathbf{$x_{22}}$+
\verb+ & \mathbf{\cdots}& \mathbf{x_{2n}} \\+
\verb+\mathbf{\vdots}&  \mathbf{vdots}&+
\verb+\mathbf{\ddots}& \mathbf{\vdots}\\+
\verb+\mathbf{x_{m1}}&  mathbf{ x_{m2}}+
\verb+ & mathbf{\cdots}&+ 
\verb+\mathbf{x_{mn}} \end{array}\right]$+\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{Will show output as:}
$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   \mathbf{X_{11}} & \mathbf{X_{12}} &  \mathbf{\cdots}  & \mathbf{X_{1n}} \\
  \mathbf{X_{21}}   & \mathbf{X_{22}}    & \mathbf{\cdots}      &  \mathbf{X_{2n}}   \\
  \mathbf{\vdots}   & \mathbf{\vdots}    &  \mathbf{\ddots}    & \mathbf{\vdots}    \\
   \mathbf{X_{m1}}  & \mathbf{X_{m2}}    & \mathbf{\cdots}     & \mathbf{X_{mn}}
\end{array}        \right]$
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are currently no `frame` environments in your `beamer` document but several `\newpage` commands. You might want to correct that. Also, what's the purpose of `.\\ `?

Comment: `beamer` is intended for presentation, not to write plain text as in article. You should devide your document body on frames!

Comment: For `\verb` to work correctly inside of a `beamer` frame`, you will need the `fragile` option (`\begin{frame}[fragile]`)

Comment: For showing longer sections of verbatim code, you might be interested in using either the `listings` or the `minted` package. Probably, using `tcolorbox` could also be useful. With this package (in combination iwth one of the before mentioned) you can show input code and compiled output in comparison without havig to repeat the code twice.

Comment: Off topic: the code `.\\ \vspace{...}` at the beginning of a new page is better input as `\vspace*{...}` with the dimension adjusted as appropriate. (The starred version of `\vspace` doesn't disappear at the top of a page.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the last page of your example document converted into `beamer`. In the first `frame`, I have not changed your use of `\verb` while I have relaced it in the second frame with the `lstlisting` environment from the `listings` package. In the third frame, I have used `tcolorbox` in combination with its `listing` library in order to get the verbatim code as well as the output without having to type the same code twice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
{\huge \textbf{EXAMPLE}}
\begin{flushleft}
\verb+$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}+
\verb+\mathbf{x{_11}}&  \mathbf{x_{12}}& + \verb+\mathbf{\cdots}&+
\verb+\mathbf{x_{1n}}& \\+
\verb+\mathbf{x_{21}}& \mathbf{$x_{22}}$+
\verb+ & \mathbf{\cdots}& \mathbf{x_{2n}} \\+
\verb+\mathbf{\vdots}&  \mathbf{vdots}&+
\verb+\mathbf{\ddots}& \mathbf{\vdots}\\+
\verb+\mathbf{x_{m1}}&  mathbf{ x_{m2}}+
\verb+ & mathbf{\cdots}&+ 
\verb+\mathbf{x_{mn}} \end{array}\right]$+\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{Will show output as:}
$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   \mathbf{X_{11}} & \mathbf{X_{12}} &  \mathbf{\cdots}  & \mathbf{X_{1n}} \\
  \mathbf{X_{21}}   & \mathbf{X_{22}}    & \mathbf{\cdots}      &  \mathbf{X_{2n}}   \\
  \mathbf{\vdots}   & \mathbf{\vdots}    &  \mathbf{\ddots}    & \mathbf{\vdots}    \\
   \mathbf{X_{m1}}  & \mathbf{X_{m2}}    & \mathbf{\cdots}     & \mathbf{X_{mn}}
\end{array}        \right]$
\end{flushleft}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   \mathbf{X_{11}} & \mathbf{X_{12}} & \mathbf{\cdots} & \mathbf{X_{1n}}  \\
   \mathbf{X_{21}} & \mathbf{X_{22}} & \mathbf{\cdots} &  \mathbf{X_{2n}} \\
   \mathbf{\vdots} & \mathbf{\vdots} & \mathbf{\ddots} & \mathbf{\vdots}  \\
   \mathbf{X_{m1}} & \mathbf{X_{m2}} & \mathbf{\cdots} & \mathbf{X_{mn}}
\end{array}\right]$
\end{lstlisting}

\textbf{Will show output as:}
$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   \mathbf{X_{11}} & \mathbf{X_{12}} &  \mathbf{\cdots}  & \mathbf{X_{1n}} \\
  \mathbf{X_{21}}   & \mathbf{X_{22}}    & \mathbf{\cdots}      &  \mathbf{X_{2n}}   \\
  \mathbf{\vdots}   & \mathbf{\vdots}    &  \mathbf{\ddots}    & \mathbf{\vdots}    \\
   \mathbf{X_{m1}}  & \mathbf{X_{m2}}    & \mathbf{\cdots}     & \mathbf{X_{mn}}
\end{array}        \right]$
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{tcblisting}{colback=white,colframe=gray}
$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   \mathbf{X_{11}} & \mathbf{X_{12}} & \mathbf{\cdots} & \mathbf{X_{1n}}  \\
   \mathbf{X_{21}} & \mathbf{X_{22}} & \mathbf{\cdots} &  \mathbf{X_{2n}} \\
   \mathbf{\vdots} & \mathbf{\vdots} & \mathbf{\ddots} & \mathbf{\vdots}  \\
   \mathbf{X_{m1}} & \mathbf{X_{m2}} & \mathbf{\cdots} & \mathbf{X_{mn}}
\end{array}\right]$
\end{tcblisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Unrelated to the `beamer` question itself but more regarding the contents of this specific frame: Instead of repeatedly typing `\mathbf{...}`, I'd use `\boldmath`. I'd also replace `\left[\begin{array}{cccc}` with `\begin{bmatrix}` as shown in the following example:

```
\boldmath{\[\begin{bmatrix}
   X_{11} & X_{12} & \cdots & X_{1n}  \\
   X_{21} & X_{22} & \cdots &  X_{2n} \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
   X_{m1} & X_{m2} & \cdots & X_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}\]}
```